# How can I disable the build/run notification in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, notifications, ide

I've recently began using Xcode as and IDE for C, but it's really annoying how when I build/run my program it makes a notification pop up in the middle of the screen and it plays a sound. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Xcode > Preferences > Behaviors**

Where it says 'build' click succeeds and uncheck

'notify using bezel or system notification'

[image]

If this solves the issue you had, please click the check mark, accepting it as an answer